# decode different object in one function

Tags: android, json, kotlin, generics, retrofit

LogonResponse

```
{
    "data": {
        "Token": "4F5696"
    },
    "success": true,
    "message": null
}
```

GameMenuResoponse

```
    "data": {
        "GameMenuModels":[{"mobileApiProductMenus": 
        ...
    },
    "success": true,
    "message": null
```

Here is different json response all of they have `"data"`, `"success"` and `"message"`.

So I add a base response

```
class BaseResponse<T>(
    @SerializedName("success") var success: Boolean = false,
    @SerializedName("message") var message: String? = "",
    @SerializedName("data") var data: T? = null
)
```

It will be success if parse jsonString separately.

```
val baseType = object : TypeToken<BaseResponse<LogonResponse>>() {}.type
val logonResponse = Gson().fromJson<BaseResponse<LogonResponse>>(jsonString, baseType)
//parse logon success
```

```
val baseType = object : TypeToken<BaseResponse<GameMenuResponse>>() {}.type
val logonResponse = Gson().fromJson<BaseResponse<GameMenuResponse>>(jsonString, baseType)
//parse GameMenu success
```

but if I decode in a generic function

```
fun <T> decode(jsonString: String): BaseMSResponse<T> {
    val baseMsType = object : TypeToken<BaseMSResponse<T>>() {}.type
    return Gson().fromJson(jsonString, baseMsType)
}
```

```
val logonResponse = decode<LogonResponse>(jsonString) //crash
val gameMenuResponse = decode(jsonString) //crash
```

error log : java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast
[image]

How to solve it? Can `TypeToken` parse object with generic?

Comment: Just a question: why do you want to create `BaseResponse` in a first place? If you won't introduce a new response sub-type then I believe it doesn't make sense to make it like this. I would suggest to use inheritance here over generic class: try to extract `success` and `message` fields to a parent class.

Comment: @Andrey Thanks for suggests. The `BaseResponse` is project legacy. Changing hundreds of response in ours project with inheritance will be more diffcult than use a generic funciton.

Answer (score 0):

As I replied above I would suggest to use inheritance over generics in this case as it will be easy to maintain. If you will want to introduce a new type of response that will have a new field then you will have to update base class  with it.

Here is the code for your case with inheritance, for deserialization I used jackson library instead of Gson:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue

fun main() {
    val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()

    val logonResponse = mapper.readValue<LogonResponse>(logonResponse)
    val gameMenuResponse = mapper.readValue<GameMenuResponse>(gameMenuResponse)
}

open class BaseResponse(
    @JsonProperty
    val success: Boolean = false,

    @JsonProperty
    val message: String? = "",
)

class LogonResponse(
    val data: TokenData
) : BaseResponse()

class TokenData(
    @JsonProperty("Token")
    val token: String
)

class GameMenuResponse(
    val data: GameMenuModelWrapper
) : BaseResponse()

class GameMenuModelWrapper(
    @JsonProperty("GameMenuModels")
    val models: List<GameMenuModel>
)


data class GameMenuModel(val mobileApiProductMenus: String?)

val logonResponse = """
        {
            "data": {
                "Token": "4F5696"
            },
            "success": true,
            "message": "ABC"
        }
    """.trimIndent()

val gameMenuResponse = """
        {
            "data": {
                "GameMenuModels":[
                    {
                        "mobileApiProductMenus": "Some Menu Here"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "success": false,
            "message": "XYZ"
        }
    """.trimIndent()
```